# SQL views with right joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have to create a view to show an overview of orders in my database. The overview doesn't need the order items, just the order id, order date, customer name, order total and order status. In the database, there are 2 tables with customer details (one for registered users and one for unregistered users), shop_customer and shop_temp_customer respectively.

I need the view to pull the customer's forename and surname from the relevant table so that I can display it on my order overview page.

Here are the table structures:

shop_orders:

```
Column Name             Column Type    Null Default

order_id                int(11)         No  None
order_date              int(255)        No  None
order_customer_id       int(11)         Yes NULL
order_temp_customer_id  int(11)         Yes NULL
order_postage           double(11,2)    No  None
order_discount          double(11,2)    No  None
order_total             double(11,2)    No  None
order_status            tinyint(1)      No  None
```

shop_customers:

```
Column Name               Column Type  Null Default

customer_id               int(11)       No  None
customer_title            varchar(255)  No  None
customer_forename         varchar(255)  No  None
customer_surname          varchar(255)  No  None
customer_company          varchar(255)  No  None
customer_contact_number   varchar(255)  No  None
customer_email            varchar(255)  No  None
customer_password         varchar(255)  No  None
customer_reference        varchar(255)  No  None
customer_marketing        tinyint(1)    No  None
customer_active           tinyint(1)    No  None
customer_decomission_date int(11)       No  None
```

shop_temp_customers:

```
Column Name                     Column Type    Null Default

temp_customer_id                int(11)         No  None
temp_customer_title             varchar(255)    No  None
temp_customer_forename          varchar(255)    No  None
temp_customer_surname           varchar(255)    No  None
temp_customer_company           varchar(255)    No  None
temp_customer_contact_number    varchar(255)    No  None
temp_customer_email             varchar(255)    No  None
temp_customer_reference         varchar(255)    No  None
temp_customer_decomission_date  int(11)         No  None
```

Here is my code for the view, but It isn't pulling any data items in:

```
CREATE VIEW shop_order_view_all_preview AS
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, c.customer_forename, c.customer_surname, tc.temp_customer_forename, tc.temp_customer_surname, o.order_total, o.order_status
FROM shop_orders o
RIGHT JOIN shop_customers c
ON c.customer_id = o.order_customer_id
RIGHT JOIN shop_temp_customers tc
ON tc.temp_customer_id = o.order_customer_id
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is some data from the tables:

shop_orders:

```
order_id order_date order_customer_id order_temp_customer_id order_postage order_discount order_total order_status
1        1322697540 2                 NULL                   12.50         0.00           1012.50     0
2        1322697540 NULL              1                      13.00         0.00           1200.00     1
```

shop_customer:

```
customer_id customer_title customer_forename customer_surname customer_company customer_telephone customer_email customer_password                 customer_reference customer_marketing customer_active customer_decomission_date
2           Mr             b                 a                d                 044444            a@test.com     098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  Poster / Flyer     1                  1               0
```

shop_temp_customer:

```
temp_customer_id temp_customer_title temp_customer_forename temp_customer_surname temp_customer_company temp_customer_contact_number temp_customer_email temp_customer_reference temp_customer_decomission_date
 1               Mr                  e                      asy                   NULL                  04444                        test@test.com       Google                  1322697540
```

Comment: the code seems fine, can you put some data from the tables please.

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung, the `order_temp_customer_id` field on the second `shop_orders` record holds a duplicate of the `order_date`, not the `temp_customer_id` value from the `shop_temp_customer` table - does this accurately reflect your data?

Comment: It did, corrected code posted now. ty :)

Comment: There cannot be non-NULL values for *both* `order_customer_id` and `order_temp_customer_id` in the orders table ?

Comment: Thanks wildplasser, that's been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One minor issue on the last line:

```
CREATE VIEW shop_order_view_all_preview AS
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, c.customer_forename, c.customer_surname, tc.temp_customer_forename, tc.temp_customer_surname, o.order_total, o.order_status
FROM shop_orders o
LEFT JOIN shop_customers c
ON c.customer_id = o.order_customer_id
LEFT JOIN shop_temp_customers tc
ON tc.temp_customer_id = o.order_temp_customer_id
--                               ^^^^^
```

- you are linking the **permanent** customer_id from the order table to the **temporary** customer table, even though you have a separate field on the order table for temporary customer IDs.

EDIT: changed RIGHT joins to LEFT joins - order table should be on **inside** of join.

Comment: The table isd only called temp as the customer is unregistered, so the customer and the order will get deleted 6 months after the order is made.

Comment: @PhilFaceplantYoung: The point is, you have separate fields on your order table for the customer ID, depending on whether it is a temporary or permanent customer. See also my comment on your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try it with left joins instead of right, as the table with ALL the orders is on the left:

```
CREATE VIEW shop_order_view_all_preview
AS
SELECT
  o.order_id,
  o.order_date,
  c.customer_forename,
  c.customer_surname,
  tc.temp_customer_forename,
  tc.temp_customer_surname,
  o.order_total,
  o.order_status
FROM shop_orders o
  LEFT JOIN shop_customers c ON c.customer_id = o.order_customer_id
  LEFT JOIN shop_temp_customers tc ON tc.temp_customer_id = o.order_customer_id
```

It's possible this does not solve the problem, but I'll give it a try before anything else.

Comment: This pulls in the data from the shop_customers table, not the shop_temp_customer data. But it pulls in SOME data, nearly there!

Comment: +1 I've updated my answer to include the left join - there's also the join field issue.

Comment: You're right with the join field issue. I assumed the join fields were correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
CREATE VIEW shop_order_view_all_preview AS
      SELECT
       shop_orders.order_id, shop_orders.order_date, shop_customers.customer_forename, shop_customers.customer_surname, shop_temp_customers.temp_customer_forename, shop_temp_customers.temp_customer_surname, shop_orders.order_total, shop_orders.order_status
      FROM 
       shop_orders, shop_customers, shop_temp_customers 
      RIGHT JOIN shop_customers 
      ON customer_id = order_customer_id
      AND
      RIGHT JOIN shop_temp_customers
      ON temp_customer_id = order_customer_id
```